# How to combine 2 indexes in 1 graph

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have 2 indexes called lodging_index and price_index.  The relation is lodgings has many prices. In the price_index there is a field called lodging_id.   We use this indexes in our api for frontend purpose. First call to our API/lodging to fetch the available lodgings and then second call (available ids/lodgings) to calculate the price (total).

This works fine and fast.  Now we want to make stats in Kibana. Can we combine the indexes in 1 graph with the lodging_id field?

Best remco

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.
You need Elasticsearch 7.10 or later. There you can use the join function to join the two indexes based on the lodging_id field. It will create a new index on top of those 2 fileds combining the data from both indexes.

Then you can then create visualizations in Kibana using this newly created joined index.

Comment: thanks! do you have example?

Answer (score 0):

Join tables is a common operation in SQL databases where data from two or more tables is combined based on a related column between them. It also called lookup table. In Elasticsearch it's not simple like other databases but it possible. Check [enrich policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html) for that.

It allows you to perform a lookup on a separate index (in your case, the price_index) during ingest time and enrich incoming documents (from the lodging_index) with data from matching documents in the other index.